# Trying to estimate cost of replacement for a stolen bike

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike, aluminum

The frame says "Nova" and "Columbus". I don't know the serial number. I believe the frame is aluminum. Purchased 2nd (or third) hand in California about 6 years ago.

[image: Picture I found on the internet of a bike with a apparently identical frame (color and text)]

Above is a picture I found on the internet of a bike with a apparently identical frame (color and text). I have some pictures of the actual bike, but they aren't as clear: [image]

Comment: I've been through this, and ideally you need an original sales receipt/invoice, from which they will calculate a depreciation of X% per year.  As you said this was used, to an insurer they'll try and pay less than your excess.   If it was an accident on the road and someone else was at fault, you could reasonably claim on their insurance for an equivalent replacement at their cost.  Sadly, many insurances aren't worth the paper they're written on.  Good luck with your claim !    You can also get sales quotes on an "equal" replacement from local bike shops, and submit them to the insurer.

Comment: That's a bummer, but fortunately doesn't match my recent very similar experience (my mountain bike was cable locked to the same spot and the cable was cut and bike taken a few months ago). My renter's insurance came through like a dream. They googled similar bikes and cut me a check for cost of replacement (minus deductible). I netted $440 for an 15 year old, poorly maintained bike that would have been hard to sell for $100. Now that it's happened again, I expect things might not go so smoothly though.

Comment: When your first bike was stolen, the insurer was willing to pay. That's quite normal. But then when a second bike was stolen at the same spot, the insurer would probably suspect negligent securing of the item.

Comment: Consider how you could change things to secure your bike better.   Cable locks are not very good, a closed and locked door between thief and bike is far better.  Good luck with your claim - questions about insurance might be slightly on-topic on Personal Finance at  https://money.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Criggie Sorry for that, I see how the title makes it sound more off topic... I really just thought this would be the place to find out more about that bike with the limited info I have.

Comment: @Carel Yes, we'll see how this round goes. FWIW, I escalated from a cable lock to U-lock... and the thieves escalated from snipping the cable to cutting the pipe it was u-locked to. Storing the bike inside our cramped apartment wouldn't be worth the cost to my marriage :)

Comment: @JoeSapp you've been hit twice for the same thing - It'll happen again.  You have to change something major.  Perhaps storing a bike anywhere outside your home is a bad idea now (I don't say that lightly)    Are there rental garages/lockup storage units available near your home?   If you're renting, then storage inside really is your best option.  If you own the place, perhaps consider the benefits of building a secure and stout shed for storage.

Comment: @JoeSapp The reason valuations are off-topic is because they depend on where, and when, as well as the obvious what.   Your bike looks like a 90s road bike, quite nice, so search ebay/craigslist/etc for something of the same era, and pick a number based on those.    If you're in a C19 affected area, bikes have gone up in value because of desire to escape public transport.  But petrol/gas prices have dropped, so car-heavy areas lack that demand and prices remain lower.   And in months, it could all be different which obsoletes any numbers quoted.   Don't take question closure personally please.

Comment: @Criggie, I totally understand closing the post. Sorry for being off topic. I agree theft would happen again. I won't be replacing the bikes for the foreseeable future, unfortunately. We do rent. Thank you for the advice about what that bike appears to be. I didn't realize it was so old! Again, sorry for my poorly worded title. I don't expect this forum to be able to assess the myriad variables that affect local used bike prices. I'm just trying to determine what kind of bike it is more or less. I know it has an aluminum frame, was quite light, and said "Nova" on it, but that's it.

Comment: @JoeSapp If it suits your riding/lifestyle, then a physically small folding bike might be a good solution.  Store it inside for security, take less space.  Downsides they're always a compromise, and they're generally not cheap unless you find a score on CL or similar.